# Raspberry Pi 4 - screen rotation

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, screen

I just got my new Raspberry Pi 4 and I'm trying to rotate the screen. Usually on previous Raspberry versions I did that simply by putting display_rotate=1 to config.txt, but when doing this on Raspberry 4 the screen is partly black and it's not rotated properly. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would interesting to understand why said functionality does not work on the new hardware: hopefully that will be in the responses

Comment: Ok, here is the solution: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=247619&p=1516639#p1516639

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101282/pi-4-screen-rotation-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround. When I ran into the same issue with the blackbox, I tried using xrandr but kept getting the error "can't open display". After some searching I found that if you're using the VC4 FKMS V3D driver (this is the default on the Raspberry Pi 4), then 90 and 270 degree rotations are not supported. So I commented out the "dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d" in /boot/config.txt and now I get the full screen in portait mode. Guess this is not the proper way, but it seems to work.

Comment: After applying this to my RetroPie build on a Pi 4, I get 'Error creating SDL window! Could not initialize EGL", and retropie will no longer run.

Answer (score 1):

On the Raspberry Pi 4, the screen rotation is (finally !) handled via [RandR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XRandR):

```
DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate left 
DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate inverted
DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate normal
```

Comment: Asking from 2021... what is the proper process to make this change permanent / happen at boot?

Answer (score 0):

For Raspberry 4 as of Nov 2020:

1. Click Raspberry Logo in the top left corner (open application menu)
2. Select "Preferences" -> "Screen Configuration". A new window "Screen Layout Editor" will be opened.
3. In the new window menu, select "Configure" -> "Screen" -> "HDMI-1" -> Orientation